# How to use jinja2 server side rendering alongside react without violating inline-script CSP

Tags: javascript, flask, reactjs, jinja2, content-security-policy

I am new to React and experimenting a bit. I would like to use it on my Flask site that uses Jinja2 templates.

People seem to recommend to render data on the server-side first instead of having to always make an initial call for data on page load. I found this [nodejs](https://github.com/mhart/react-server-example) example but it just puts the data on the page in a global variable in an inline script tag. I was wondering if there was a clean way to do this other than just putting the data on the page inside an inline script tag. Because of my secure CSP policy I can't use inline scripts or eval.

Is there an standard pattern people use to render data for React on the server without using an inline variable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can certainly use it on sites that have server side rendering via Jinja.  The question becomes - what do you want to update on the page without reloading?  Usually, the component state in React is updated via user interaction or a changing data source (i.e. db API).

My experience has been to render (via Jinja) the static page data and then use React components to update based on and/or listen for changes to the state of an API (maybe through [Flask-Restful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask-restful)).  These APIs can be accessed through React's life cycle methods (usually 'getInitialState' or 'setState')

For example - you may have portions of your site that are rendered server-side in `layout.html` and then the `{% block content %}` is rendered client side by the React js components.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}


{% block content %}

<h2>Some Header</h2>

<script type="text/jsx" src="/scripts/ReactComponent1.js">
</script>

<div id="one">
<!-- This element's contents will be replaced with ReactComponent1. -->
</div>

<script type="text/jsx" src="/scripts/ReactComponent2.js">
</script>

<div id="two">
<!-- This element's contents will be replaced with ReactComponent2. -->
</div>



{% endblock %}
```

I really recommend going through the [React Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) and trying to apply it to a Flask App.

Comment: how will you use react to do dynamic content from database though?

Comment: @Zion By using AJAX within your React class functions.

Comment: For render all contents that contain react components just on server side, how can I do?

Comment: @incleaf Depends on what you mean... If you want to render the data and use that for hydrating your react component, you can just add it to a data attribute and hydrate client-side without any additional API/Ajax calls.  If you want to hydrate the component server-side, you'll need to prop up a node/react rendering server and pass your page through that server before delivering it to the client.

Comment: What is it exactly that causes `<div id="one">` to be replaced with ReactComponent1?

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a data attribute on the `element` where the component will be mounted (or any other element that you can find):

```
<div id="one" data-component-initial="{}">
</div>
```

Then in your react scripts, use this data to render the component instead of an ajax call.